# Cannot see BizTalk pipeline assembly dependencies in BizTalk Admin Console

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-pipelines

We have a BizTalk Pipeline which uses a custom pipeline component. There are various assembly versions of the pipeline component available and we wanted to know the version with which this pipeline was compiled with.
We loaded the pipeline in the resources (Add as BizTalk Assemblies and Resources, tried both ), but the dependencies tab does not show any component dependencies.
Tried with other Pipeline Projects as well to verify if this behaviour is exhibited by all other pipelines as well. And found it be true.
Is this an expected behaviour or am I missing something.

Version - BizTalk Server 2013 / Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 2):

The same behaviour occurs in BizTalk 2013 R2.
It only shows which Send Ports or Receive Ports use the Pipeline, but the Using: section is blank and does not show you what Pipeline Components are referenced.

You can go the the Send & Receive Ports themselves and see the component names there, but that will not show you what version it is using.

If your different versions of the Pipeline Component have the same Strong Name Key and only differ in the assembly version number then it will either use the latest version from the GAC, or if not found in the GAC it will use the version in the Pipeline Components folder.

Also see this blog [Find BizTalk Pipeline Component References](https://psrathoud.wordpress.com/2016/11/10/find-biztalk-pipeline-component-references/)

Comment: Is this behavior specific to BizTalk pipeline assemblies only ?  I tried adding another BizTalk asembly which contains only maps and references other schema assemblies. In this case, it did show the dependent assemblies under the dependencies tab and application to which it belongs.
**Edit **
In any case, any BizTalk project is a BizTalk project. What difference would it make what BizTalk artifacts it contains. It would be interesting to see what behavior it exhibits when the assembly has a map as well as a pipeline.

Comment: @VaibhavVerma  Added a link to a blog which describes using a database query to find the Pipeline Components Dependencies